# How do I turn a POSTed JSON value into PHP?

Tags: php, json, api, post, get

As a test, this JSON data is being POSTed to my website:

```
{
    "order": {
        "id": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "status": "new",
        "total_btc": {
            "cents": 100000000,
            "currency_iso": "BTC"
        },
        "total_native": {
            "cents": 2263,
            "currency_iso": "USD"
        },
        "custom": "123456789",
        "button": {
            "type": "buy_now",
            "name": "Test Item",
            "description": null,
            "id": null
        },
        "transaction": {
            "hash": "4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b",
            "confirmations": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Since it is being sent server-to-server I cannot visibly see the data. I have tried sending the $_POST array to a text file, but it comes up blank. What I think I need to do is:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonData);
```

But how do I set the variable $jsonData?

Comment: Is it **required** to be json? Why not send general uri-style `&` separated data?

Comment: The question is unclear, what is sending this and to what page? If its sent by PHP, you have to echo the json data on screen.

Comment: To look at the `$_POST[]` array, just use `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`

Comment: https://coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/callbacks is more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) for reading raw POST query.

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: I actually tried this earlier, but I cannot remember the results. I will upload and try again.

Comment: $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
file_put_contents('coinbase.txt', $data);
printed Array

Comment: Don't hurry. Look what is you get
       $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
       file_put_contents('post.log', $data);

Comment: You are awesome, that did it! I have no idea how I missed trying that, but it was the key.

Comment: $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE); 
    $text = print_r($data,true);
    file_put_contents('coinbase.txt', $text);

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I now have some nice looking arrays printed to a .txt

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, store the sting obtained to a variable and then decoding it?

```
$postedJsonData= '{"order":{"id":null,"created_at":null,"status":"new","total_btc":
{"cents":100000000,"currency_iso":"BTC"},"total_native":
{"cents":2263,"currency_iso":"USD"},"custom":"123456789","button":
{"type":"buy_now","name":"Test Item","description":null,"id":null},"transaction":
{"hash":"4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b","confirmations":0}}}';

var_dump(json_decode($postedJsonData, true));
```

The true parameter would return an associative array

Comment: The data is being sent to my site, it is not already included.

Comment: Have you tried, as the answer suggested, print_r($_POST). I should show you the data that are being sent to you.

Comment: I have tried var_dump and print_r However, since I am unable to actually view the page as the POST is sent I have to send the results to a text file and nothing is passed.

Answer (score 0):

$data = json_decode($jsonData, True);

Comment: I can set assoc to TRUE, but I still need to place a value in the $jsonData variable.